# Java being installed in 2 different directories on MacOS

Tags: java, eclipse, java-11

I'm trying to run Java 11 on eclipse, but it keeps on insisting on running Java 10 instead. Note that I don't have any JAVA_HOME environment variables set up, although when I did set it up to the folder for JDK 11 it still ran v10.

Turns out that `/usr/bin/java` is actually pointing to `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java` which I presume is actually Java version 10.

I have java version 11 installed at `/library/java/javavirtualmachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/`.

Is there any reason why I have 2 folders for Java? Can I delete one of them?

Answer (score 0):

It’s not uncommon to have multiple versions of Java installed, especially if you’re supporting a large number of applications and systems.

You can remove either one of them if you want, but you don’t have to.  In the `/usr/bin` directory, you can unlink or relink the java, javac, jar, keytool (IIRC) to what you want the default Java version to be.

I often create a symbolic link in `/library/java/default` to reference what I want my default version to be. That way, I never have to touch the `/usr/bin` directory.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, in the Eclipse settings you can tell it which JDK to use.

The Java installer should setup JAVA_HOME for you, actually, but you can override like so, for example to set to JDK 8.

```
if which java > /dev/null; then export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v1.8); fi
```

Sure, you can delete one them, but Java 11 is going to be the longer supported one.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse you can have multiple Javas set up and individual projects can use different JREs. When you add a new Java to your system you will have to tell Eclipse about it.

Look in the Preferences in 'Java > Installed JREs' to see which JREs Eclipse currently knows about. You may have to add Java 11 to the list here.

In your projects look in the project Properties in the 'Java Build Path' to see which Java is selected for that project and change if required.

In the 'Run > Run Configurations' dialog find your program and look at the JRE which is selected to run the program.